# Manually flushing a write-through cache

Tags: cpu-cache

Does it make any sense in flushing the CPU cache manually, if it is implemented as a write-through cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a word is written at a write-through (WT) cache by a store instruction, it is also sent to the following level of the memory hierarchy ([see cache entry at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29)). Hence, cache blocks at the WT cache are clean, that is, are coherent with their copies at the next level, and write-backs would not be necessary.

WT invalidations could be required in case of Direct Memory Acceses (DMA) that make cache contents stale, but, as far as I know, these are not manually operations, but OS or hardware driven.

Related to manually flushing, for example, according to the Intel Architecture Software Developer’s Manual (Volume 2, Instruction Set Reference):

WBINVD — Write Back and Invalidate Cache This instruction writes back all modified cache lines in the processor’s internal cache to main memory and invalidates (flushes) the internal caches.

So I think that, in case of a WT cache, this instruction just invalidates all the cache lines.

Comment: Thanks chus. If the backing store for a cache line is volatile (DMA), then isn't invalidating the cache ideal than flushing it?

Comment: You are right. I have edited my answer to make it more accurate.

Comment: Yes. Now since WT cache line entries are always clean, an explicit flush of the cache line should not result in a write to actual memory isn't it? CPU should just discard the flush instruction.

Comment: I think so. By the way, be aware that the cache flush instruction is a privileged one. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756825/cpu-cache-flush) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745665/wbinvd-instruction-usage)